# How can I use jQuery to convert an HTML table into <div>'s?

Tags: jquery, html

How could I go about converting an HTML table (I will provide code below) into `<div>` elements? Long story short, I am using a PHP script that outputs contents into an HTML table and it has proven very difficult to edit the PHP and convert the table elements into `<div>`'s. Below is the HTML table code:

```
<table><tbody><tr data-marker="0"><td class="mapp-marker"><img class="mapp-icon" src="http://www.walmartchicago.com/wp-content/plugins/mappress-google-maps-for-wordpress/icons/walmart-yellow.png"></td><td><b>Walmart Neighborhood Market<br></b><a href="#" class="poi_list_directions">Get Directions</a></td></tr><tr data-marker="1"><td class="mapp-marker"><img class="mapp-icon" src="http://www.walmartchicago.com/wp-content/plugins/mappress-google-maps-for-wordpress/icons/walmart-red.png"></td><td><b>Walmart Express<br></b><a href="#" class="poi_list_directions">Get Directions</a></td></tr><tr data-marker="2"><td class="mapp-marker"><img class="mapp-icon" src="http://www.walmartchicago.com/wp-content/plugins/mappress-google-maps-for-wordpress/icons/walmart-red.png"></td><td><b>Walmart Express<br></b><a href="#" class="poi_list_directions">Get Directions</a></td></tr><tr data-marker="3"><td class="mapp-marker"><img class="mapp-icon" src="http://www.walmartchicago.com/wp-content/plugins/mappress-google-maps-for-wordpress/icons/walmart-blue.png"></td><td><b>Walmart Supercenter<br></b><a href="#" class="poi_list_directions">Get Directions</a></td></tr><tr data-marker="4"><td class="mapp-marker"><img class="mapp-icon" src="http://www.walmartchicago.com/wp-content/plugins/mappress-google-maps-for-wordpress/icons/walmart-blue.png"></td><td><b>Walmart Supercenter<br></b><a href="#" class="poi_list_directions">Get Directions</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: As difficult as it may be to edit the PHP to generate content in divs, it most likely is the best method to use here.

Comment: While my answer will provide you the jQuery solution you've requested. Perhaps the best solution would be to do what I just did, only before the string is output from PHP?

Answer (score 17):

No need to loop through the elements and copy the attributes, just pull the table contents as a string and run a simple string replace ...

```
$('table').replaceWith( $('table').html()
   .replace(/<tbody/gi, "<div id='table'")
   .replace(/<tr/gi, "<div")
   .replace(/<\/tr>/gi, "</div>")
   .replace(/<td/gi, "<span")
   .replace(/<\/td>/gi, "</span>")
   .replace(/<\/tbody/gi, "<\/div")
);
```

... or, if you want an unordered list ...

```
$('table').replaceWith( $('table').html()
   .replace(/<tbody/gi, "<ul id='table'")
   .replace(/<tr/gi, "<li")
   .replace(/<\/tr>/gi, "</li>")
   .replace(/<td/gi, "<span")
   .replace(/<\/td>/gi, "</span>")
   .replace(/<\/tbody/gi, "<\/ul")
);
```

This will also retain your classes and attributes.

**Perhaps the best solution isn't jQuery related, but PHP ... you could use PHP's `str_replace()` to do the same thing, only before outputting from PHP?**

```
$table_str = //table string here
$UL_str = str_replace('<tbody', '<ul id="table"', $table_str);
$UL_str = str_replace('<tr', '<li', $UL_str);
$UL_str = str_replace('</tr', '</li', $UL_str);
$UL_str = str_replace('<td', '<span', $UL_str);
$UL_str = str_replace('</td', '</span', $UL_str);
$UL_str = str_replace('</tbody', '</ul"', $UL_str);
```

Comment: Basically, take the entire table as a string, replace the `<tbody>` with `<div id="table">`, the `<tr>` with `<div>`, and the `<td>` with `<span>`.

Comment: This approach fails when there's more than one table in the page.

Comment: Simply replace the initial selectors `$('table')` with the selectors required `$('#my_table')`.

Comment: So you're suggesting to duplicate the same code for 10 tables? A better approach would be: `$('table').each(function(){var var $this = $(this);$this.replaceWith( $this.html().replace( ... )); });

Comment: You're off-topic. He asked "How could I go about converting an HTML table...", that's what I answered. But, yes, what you suggest should work great for converting multiple tables at once.

Comment: @TimothyAaron - what if i have rowspan and colspan in table as well

Answer (score 4):

It does seem like a crazy thing to have to do. I just wrote a jQuery plugin to do this though.  Working with an old web app where we don't want to really dig into the backend code and are on a limited budget. So, just taking the data that is dumped out in tables, converting them to divs, so I can float them around, style them up and make the data look better.

The system is rending data that is not really 'tabular' data.

https://github.com/ryandoom/jquery-plugin-table-to-div

If anyone is interested in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> Long story short, I am using a PHP script that outputs contents into an HTML table and it has proven very difficult to edit the PHP and convert the table elements into 's.

Using tables for non-tabular contents is frowned upon. However, if you've already served content in a table, and it looks well, you should **not** use jQuery to turn the table in divs, just to get rid off the table.

If you still want to use jQuery to turn the table in a div, you have to consider the structure of the `<div>` elements. Then, loop through each table row, loop through each table cell, and move the contents to a newly created `<div>`. At the end, replace the table with the set of `<div>`s.

Comment: A styled unordered list would be the appropriate container for this type of content. You can use a CSS background for the marker on the LI.