# Convert tables to divs and keep attributes jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I found [an answer on how to change tables into divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229856/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-convert-an-html-table-into-divs/) but how do I keep the attributes of the tables? I wish to keep classes and id's of the converted tables.

This is the code I'm using:

```
 $('table').each(function (){
        $(this).replaceWith( $(this).html()
            .replace(/<tbody/gi, "<div class='table'")
            .replace(/<tr/gi, "<div class='ccbnOutline'")
            .replace(/<\/tr>/gi, "</div>")
            .replace(/<td/gi, "<span")
            .replace(/<\/td>/gi, "</span>")
            .replace(/<\/tbody/gi, "<\/div")
        );
    });
```

Comment: Do you have to do this dynamically, or can you change it into divs ahead of time?

Comment: @Matthew im not sure i understand your question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i wish to keep classes and id's of the converted tables

If you only want those two: At some point in whatever code you're using to do this, you should have a reference to the old `table` and the new `div`, probably in jQuery objects. So:

```
theNewDiv.attr("id", theOldTable.attr("id"));
theNewDiv.attr("class", theOldTable.attr("class"));
```

---

Now that you've shown your code:

```
$('table').each(function (){
    var theOldTable = $(this);
    var theNewDiv = $(theOldTable.html()
        .replace(/<tbody/gi, "<div class='table'")
        .replace(/<tr/gi, "<div class='ccbnOutline'")
        .replace(/<\/tr>/gi, "</div>")
        .replace(/<td/gi, "<span")
        .replace(/<\/td>/gi, "</span>")
        .replace(/<\/tbody/gi, "<\/div")
    );
    theNewDiv.attr("id", theOldTable.attr("id"));
    theNewDiv.attr("class", theOldTable.attr("class"));
    theOldTable.replaceWith(theNewDiv);
});
```

Comment: awesome! i actually tried pasting the code there, but i see there is another line added so maybe thats why it wasnt working.. and sorry for my bad question (without code)

Comment: @SolidSnake: You fixed it, that's all that matters! :-)

Comment: i tried adding .not('css path'), to a table i dont want converted, but its still converting the table .. is there any alternatives to .not() ?

Comment: @SolidSnake: `$('table').not('selector-here').each(...` will definitely leave out tables matching `selector-here`. Perhaps you put it elsewher?

Comment: hm. something is wrong with my replace tag code.. it still leaves the table tag but replaces everything inside the table.. maybe that's why its not working..